# How can I send a playable part of a .mp4 in flask without range headers

Tags: python, flask

Lets say i have this endpoint in flask.

```
@app.route('/video.mp4', methods=['GET'])
def video_send():
    return flask.send_file('video.mp4')
```

This sends the video file raw with a 200 status. The client thats making this request does not support range byte requests with 206 statuses. However, i can still make a request to the endpoint with some url parameter such as `/video.mp4?skip_bytes=50000`. The video file was encoded with handbrake and "web optimizations" where enabled. Is it possible to be able to send a certain range of bytes of that file and still have it be completely playable?